# Task Scheduler Doesn't Use Default Program

Tags: perl, windows-8, scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a Perl script.  In Windows 7, I was able to just specify the script, and Task Scheduler automatically run it using the default program, the Perl interpreter.  In Windows 8, for some reason it is opening the file in notepad, even though the Perl interpreter is correctly associated with the file type.  I'm having to setup the task to execute the Perl interpreter and then pass the script and its arguments as arguments to the interpreter.

As a side note, the icons on my Perl scripts in File Explorer appears to be a text file, even though I can double click on it and it executes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should find your perl.exe file and schedule to run a command like this:

```
c:\somewhere\somedir\perl.exe d:\whatever\myfile.pl
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am doing now under Windows 8.  I just didn't need to on previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

Personally for running Perl scripts via Task Scheduler, I've always written a batch file as a wrapper, and scheduled Windows to run the batch file instead of running the Perl script directly.

(There are probably smarter ways to do it, but I don't use Windows very frequently and don't have much interest in learning the intricacies of Task Scheduler. Batch files have been around for long enough for me to understand, and they seem to do the trick.)